# Is there a limit to how many loops I can have in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This may be a really stupid question, but I feel the need to ask it. Is there any limit to how many e.g. if statements I can have in my code?

At the moment I'm creating PHP pages for a website. One of the pages is integrating some database tables into the PHP code. I may have created it a bit stupid so now it's a lot of unnecessary work.

My real question is, is there a limit to how many if statements I can have, if so, what limits it? I would guess the loading speed is slowed down if there is a lot to process?

E.g: this is a bit of the code I use and this is copied like 50 times and then changed a bit for the specific table and row.

```
<?php require_once('dbconn.php');
                              $sql = "SELECT week0_th_0 FROM training_week0";
                              $result = $conn->query($sql);
                                ob_start();
                                  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                  // output data of each row
                                  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                      echo
                                      $row["week0_th_0"];
                                      }
                                           } else {
                                               echo "0 results";
                                           }
                                               $echo_week0_th_0 = ob_get_clean();?>
```

I'm wondering in code in general, thanks!

Comment: A) No B) an `if` statement is not a "loop"` C) copy/pasting is a bad way to go about coding

Comment: There is no explicit limit, but if you find yourself asking this question, then it's time to look at how your code is built. Replace those 50 chunks with one function that takes arguments for table and row.

Comment: There isn't a specific limit, but the more you use them the more stack they will use resulting in slower execution, and ```if``` is a conditional statement. I thought i was first to comment, but no my data speed says otherwise.

Comment: Your code here is not formatted well, the ending brackets `}` should line up with the start of the expression such as `if` or `while`. Everything nested inside any 2 brackets should be indented and not lined up with the expression/ending bracket. Notice how much cleaner [this looks](https://pastebin.com/UU7DyTtu) for example.

Comment: Also note that your real issue here is that you have fields and tables named like `week0` and `week1`. This is generally an indication of poor schema design. Your variations should be denoted by rows, not by columns. E.g., you probably want one `week` table with a field like `week_number`, and all the rows in that one table. Then you can perform your query with a single join and a loop rather than 50 cut-and-pasted chunks of nearly identical code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no practical limit to the number of `if` statements. Since you're asking from a practical standpoint, I think that's the best answer for you.

I'm sure there are limits around how much php can be read and run, but these limits are so massive you'll have problems reading and knowing what your code does way beforehand (for the academically curious I'm not too sure about php but I know java can handle methods up to about 64k lines, and there's no additional limits on `if` or `for` statements or anything like that).

As far as speed is concerned, yes it's more code to be read and executed by a machine, but `if` statements have no practical effect (for the curious you can learn about something in computer science called big-O notation).

To address a point a couple of people have commented in your question, copying an pasting code is usually a sign that you could use methods/functions to clean up a lot of that repetition.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no explicit limit, or really an implicit limit, from a PHP perspective.

There's likely an implicit limit from a human factors / maintainability perspective.

Often, if you find yourself repeating the same series of statements again and again, it's worthwhile to create a single reusable function with those statements in it that accepts parameters for things that vary from place to place you want to use it.